# How to identify only words that are united by "-" in R?

Tags: r, string

Let's assume, I have the following text in R:

```
x = "The effects in the medium-term of an appreciation of the exchange rate are still to be carefully assessed in our projections. However, we can observe in the short-term that the our pogramme of purchasing asset-backed securities had a positive impact on overall economic activity"
```

How can I get only the following:

```
# medium-term
# short-term
# asset-backed
```

Basically, I would need to extract only those words that are linked by a "-".

Can anyone help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work:

```
library(stringr)
str_extract_all(x, '\\b[a-z]+-[a-z]+\\b')[[1]]
[1] "medium-term"  "short-term"   "asset-backed"
```

Answer (score 1):

In base R, you could use :

```
regmatches(x, gregexpr('\\w+-\\w+', x))[[1]]
#[1] "medium-term"  "short-term"   "asset-backed"
```

Comment: Thanks so much to both of you. I will mark the correct answer when SO will allow me to do so. I usually mark the correct answers to the respondent who has the lowest score. Thanks again!